# SVG background image has strange lines on top

Tags: css, svg

```css
.banner{
  width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    margin: 0;
    height: 486px;
    padding: 0;
}
.banner img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
span.img {
    background-image:url(https://cdn.aqeed.com/assets/images/qeedo/qeedofamily.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    height: 78%;
    width: 21%;
    left: auto;
    right: 12%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="banner banner-product aq-container">
        <img src="https://cdn.aqeed.com/assets/images/banners/medicalbanner.svg" alt="Request Quote">
            <span style="background-image:url(https://cdn.aqeed.com/assets/images/qeedo/qeedofamily.svg)" class="img"></span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am using a lot of SVG images in my website, but lately some appeared to have a **strange line on the top edge of the svg**, and some have this line appear only on small sizes (mobile), I requested a new svg from the designer but its obvious that the svg itself is clear, as seen in source panel of the browser.
this is happening on all browsers.
below is a screenshot of the edgeof the svg, the lines appear under yellow marker:

[image]

this is the second one on mobile:

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your code in codepen, it's hard to help without that. Can you provide the svg code?

Comment: Ok i will update the question

Comment: Can you tell me what size the svg image is?

Comment: I am asking because if I make the svg bigger on your code snippet, the lines disappear. This is due to the fact that browsers and Illustrator see things differently when resizing. So the best solution is to first resize the svg, to be somewhat the size of what you need on your web page.

Comment: open the svg link in new tab and inspect, its 1358px width and 1310px height and i want it to be proportion, responsive on the screen size, that's why I have made width and height percentage (%)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell which part of the image your first thumbnail is indicating. But the second image corresponds to the top of the hospital.

The hospital is actually not a proper vector, it is a PNG file embedded as a `<pattern>`.  I suspect the cause of your stray lines could be just some rounding issues that occur when a large object (1092x790 pattern & image) are scaled down to very small sizes (on mobile).  The lines that you see may be the bottom of the hospital image as it repeats vertically in the `<pattern>`.

There are actually two of these image patterns in the SVG.  The second one is a big grey PNG that is used for the road at the bottom.

My advice is to ask your designer to remove the two PNG images from the SVG and redraw them as vectors.  I have high confidence that will get rid of your problem.

And as a bonus, it will also shrink your SVG significantly. Those two PNG images take up 72k of your 137k SVG file.  If you change those images to vectors, you can nearly halve your file size.

Comment: did you check the first svg (qeedofamily) ? the first thumbnail is corresponsing to the svg of the 3 people next to each other

Comment: Ah. I didn't notice that one at first.  Yes the same thing applies there. That is not a proper SVG either. It is almost entirely a large 1358 x 1310 PNG image.  Looks like your designer has more work to do.

Comment: You can see for yourself by loading the SVGs into a text editor. Most of the each SVG consists of Base64 encoded PNG image(s).